# Part assignment is not a symbol

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

read some related posts and found no solution. For a list defined like this

```
m = {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0, 1.5, 1.6};
```

when I define this function

```
f[m__] :=m[[Range[2, Length[Evaluate[m]], 1]]] = {{r, x, y, u, v, n, l, w, 
  s}, m[[Range[2, Length[Evaluate[m]], 1]]]}\[Transpose];
```

I get an error telling me the list in the part assignment is not a symbol.

I want to be able to build a function that does the operation on different lists and takes the name of the list as an argument.

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do. what is `f` supposed to do?

Comment: I'd venture `m = Transpose[{{r, x, y, u, v, n, l, w, s}, Rest@m}]` will accomplish what it appears you're after...

Comment: Or, maybe `m[[2 ;;]] = Transpose[{{r, x, y, u, v, n, l, w, s}, m[[2 ;;]]}]` is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Take a look at [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) and evaluation control in general - the `Evaluate` is not needed in this case for example. The error stems from the fact that `m` is evaluated to a list before it's passed to `f`, which causes `Part` to complain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify function argument?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/how-to-modify-function-argument) - See also [Modifying parameters: Set::setps in the part assignment is not a symbol](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60606/modifying-parameters-setsetps-in-the-part-assignment-is-not-a-symbol)

Answer (score 1):

```
f2[list_] := Transpose[{{r, x, y, u, v, n, l, w, s}, list[[2 ;;]]}]

f2[m]
```

> {{r, 0.3}, {x, 0.4}, {y, 0.5}, {u, 0.6}, {v, 0.7}, {n, 0.9}, {l, 
>     1.}, {w, 1.5}, {s, 1.6}}