# Flatten not working

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, conditional

I am trying to modify some code proposed here [Part assignment is not a symbol](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197926/part-assignment-is-not-a-symbol)

and I cannot manage to make Flatten work. I write

```
m = {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0, 1.5, 1.6}; 
f[list_] := Flatten[Module[{titi = {r, x, y, u, v, n, l, w, s}}, 
  Transpose[{titi, Rest@list}]] /; Length[list] > Length[titi]];
```

and I get

```
f[m]
```

> `{{r, 0.3}, {x, 0.4}, {y, 0.5}, {u, 0.6}, {v, 0.7}, {n, 0.9}, {l, 1.}, {w, 1.5}, {s, 1.6}}`

Answer (score 16):

`f[...] := Module[{...}, ... /; condition]` is a very special syntax (documented in the Details section of [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html)). It only works if the right-hand side of the `:=` operator contains a `Module`.  In your example, it contains a `Flatten`, the `Module` being buried at a lower level.

What is important to remember is that a `/;` condition inside of a `Module`/`Block`/`With` must always go together with a `:=` or `:>`.  It is useful to think of `/;` as going with the `:=` and not with `Module`.

In fact, normally we write

```
f[...] /; condition := ...
```

The reason to use

```
f[...] := Module[{...}, ... /; condition]
```

is to be able to use local `Module` variables in the condition. More precisely, the purpose is to avoid computing things twice. We might need to compute a quantity for the condition, but we may want to use the very same quantity when computing the result of the function. This would not be possible with `f[...] /; condition := ...`.

---

As @kglr showed, putting the `Flatten` inside of the `Module` will fix this.

Comment: Wonderful explanation! (Say, we should be able to have memoized, then, functions which occur only under `condition`, utilizing a form of what we "normally" write within the memoization, yeah?) {checking my understanding, asking for an extension of your answer, if this requires another question to be prosed, I will need to learn fully what I can and cannot "ask" for in a comment!} As always, great work, very clear and understandable!

Comment: Is it correct to say that this phenomena is due to Condition being programmed internally via pattern matching on Module/With/Block and not on f[Module/With/Block]? Is it also correct that this is nowhere mentioned in the docs (I didn't see it anyway)? Is it fair to say that this amounts to a general shortcoming of the entire pattern-matching based programming model?

Comment: @berniethejet 1. It's implemented in terms of `RuleCondition` and `$ConditionHold`. These are not documented, and I never took the time to fully understand them, but you can search this site to find many discussions. 2. The syntax I described is documented under Details in the Module/Block/With doc pages. It is not widely known, but it's _the way_ to implement the typical error-handling behaviour we see in built-in functions: if something goes wrong, the function does not evaluate. This feature is needed because thing often go wrong late in the processing. 3. I do not see any shortcoming.

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs. I guess what I am trying to say is that for a new user there is no obvious reason why f[...] := Flatten[Module[{...}, ... /; condition]] shouldn't work. It is only once they understand that everything is based on pattern-matching that they can accept these sorts of seemingly arbitrary constraints.

Comment: @berniethejet Yes, it's not obvious. I link to think of it as coming from the LHS: `f[x_ /; IntegerQ[x]] := ...` can be changed to `f[x_] /; IntegerQ[x] := ...` can be changed to `f[x_] := ... /; Integer[Q]` (!) can be changed to `f[x_] := Module[{}, ...; ... /; IntegerQ[x]]`. But there it stops. It does not go deeper.

Answer (score 10):

Put `Flatten` inside  `Module`:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[list_] := Module[{titi = {r, x, y, u, v, n, l, w, s}}, 
  Flatten@Transpose[{titi, Rest@list}] /; Length[list] > Length[titi]]

f[m]
```

> {r, 0.3, x, 0.4, y, 0.5, u, 0.6, v, 0.7, n, 0.9, l, 1., w, 1.5, s, 1.6}

You could also use `Riffle[titi, Rest@list]` instead of `Flatten[Transpose[{titi, Rest@list}]]`.

Comment: Does your last note imply that we can, in general, replace `Flatten[Transpose[{settobeappliedtolist,Rest@list}]]` with `Riffle[settobeappliedtolist,Rest@list]`?

Comment: @CATrevillian, I think so.

Comment: Many thanks everyone