# How can I access to the needed part of this expression?

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment

I have defined a list like this:

```
F[1][t] = ConstantArray[a1, 10]
```

Now I want to assign to some of the elements the value `1`; I try with this:

```
F[1][t][[2 ;; 4]] = 1
```

But I get an error saying that

> "F[1][t] in the part assignment is not a symbol"

It seems this happens because Mathematica thinks I want to assign a value to the elements 2 to 4 of `[1]` which is not a symbol in fact. How can I access to the elements of the list `F[1][t]` and assign them a value?

Comment: You might find something [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Set%3A%3Asetps) to help

Comment: You have to set them through a temporary variable: `F[1][t] = ConstantArray[a1, 10];
Module[{temp = F[1][t]},
  temp[[2 ;; 4]] = 1;
  F[1][t] = temp;
  ];
F[1][t]` [See here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60608/72682)